# Git: The requested URL returned error: 403 | incorrect authentication

Tags: linux, git, github, debian

Full Context: I'm currently on a Debian system which is Pop_OS! to be specific which I recently transition to from Windows 10 if it can be relevant. now I am currently doing the '100 days of python' I have now successfully committed the files I need on git but when I pushed it out to github I accidentally signed in using another account that I have.

so now when perform the `git push` command, I get this:

`remote: Permission to ActuallyCasealop/100-days-of-python.git denied to Casealop.`
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ActuallyCasealop/100-days-of-python.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

`Actuallycasealop` is the intended account and I accidentally logged in with `casealop` when prompted to connect github to git. how can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The `403` error you're encountering indicates that the GitHub credentials you are using do not have permission to push to the `ActuallyCasealop/100-days-of-python.git` repository. Since you've accidentally authenticated with the wrong GitHub account (`Casealop`), you'll need to update your credentials to the correct account (`ActuallyCasealop`).

If you want to directly change the saved credentials, you could use:

```
git config --global credential.username "ActuallyCasealop"
```

After updating this, the next time you `git push`, you should be prompted for a password. You can also use a personal access token instead of a password if two-factor authentication is enabled.